# Open a view on image Click in cover flow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, coverflow

I am using cover flow library in my project.My cover flow consist of many images.What I want to do is when I click on that image another View Controller should  gets open.
Please tell me how to open another view on that image click.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What coverflow library are you using?

Comment: @JustSid http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/09/how-to-add-coverflow-effect-on-your-iphone-app-openflow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday. I had to change something in the framework.
Add these two methods in the interface

```
@interface AFOpenFlowView : UIView
- (AFItemView *)selectedCoverView;
- (UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Add the implementations of these two methods inside of the .m file

```
@implementation AFOpenFlowView

- (AFItemView *)selectedCoverView {
return selectedCoverView;
}

- (UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return scrollView;
}
```

Set a UITapGestureRecognizer in the view controller where you're using the AFOpenFlowView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(screenTapped:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
}
```

At the end implement the method to handle the tap on the screen

```
- (void)screenTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {

CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:[af scrollView]];

if (CGRectContainsPoint([[af selectedCoverView] frame], point)) {
            // Write here the code to open your view
            // Use [af selectedCoverView].number to get the index of the selected cover
    NSLog(@"selected cover view: %d", [af selectedCoverView].number);
}

}
```

Hope it's going to save you some time! ;)

Comment: it works but there is one problem now this method only gets called if any of the button gets pressed what to do?

Comment: may you please explain me - (void)screenTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap {
 method code

Comment: All that the method does is to get the position of the tap inside of the scrollview inside of AFOpenFlowView and then checks if frame of the selected cover view contains the tap. If it does, than you can perform any action you want inside of the if block.

Comment: @singingAtom:i tried implementing your above code i m getting error at af.wat should i do if i m to avoid the error..

Answer (score 1):

Please try other [FlowCover](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m) this is very easy to use...

Thanks